# Load Javascript file with Javascript based on URL

Tags: javascript

Can I use Javascript to load a Javascript file in HTML based on a string in URL?
For example something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.href.indexOf("DEUTCH") != -1) 
    {
    include ('javascript_deutch.js)
    }
    else 
    {
    include ('javascript_english.js)
    }
</script>
```

I cannot use any other method like PHP or something.

---

Thanks for the help guys. 
Unfortunately none of these things seem to work.

This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.href.indexOf("DEUTCH") != -1) {
   document.head.innerHTML+='<script src="javascript_deutch.js"></script>';
}else{
   document.head.innerHTML+='<script src="javascript_english.js"></script>';
}
</script>
```

ended up just displaying a message at the top of my page:

```
'; }else{ document.head.innerHTML+=''; }
```

And this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var script = document.createElement('script');
if (location.path.indexOf("DEUTCH") > -1) {
script.src = 'javascript_deutch.js';
} else {
script.src = 'javascript_english.js';
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

did not request the files on the server at all.
Am I missing something?

Comment: As for the error in caused by my answer; [I've edited it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33861148).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `<script>` tag dynamically:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
if (location.path.indexOf("DEUTCH") > -1) {
  script.src = 'javascript_deutch.js';
} else {
  script.src = 'javascript_english.js';
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way without framework:

```
var _script = document.createElement('script');
_script.src = 'fileName.js';
document.body.appendChild(_script);
```

May be will be good to isolate this into separate function like this:

```
function includeJsFile(fileName) {
     var _script = document.createElement('script');
    _script.src = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(_script);
}
```

But may be will be good for you to check 
http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Why not. Just add them in the script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.href.indexOf("DEUTCH") != -1) {
   document.head.innerHTML+='&lt;script src="javascript_deutch.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;';
}else{
   document.head.innerHTML+='<&lt;script src="javascript_english.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this method worked for me:

```
<script>
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + language-file + '.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```